# What is the name of this machine learning algorithm that is based in the maximum likelihood estimation?

Tags: machine-learning, maximum-likelihood

There is a set of random variables $x_i,i=1,2,\dots,N_x$ whose distribution depends on some parameters $p_i,i=1,2,\dots,N_p$. The [maximum likelihood estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation) for the parameters based on a single observation of the random variable is just that which maximizes the likelihood function $\mathscr{L}(p)=f(x|p)$ where $f(x|p)$ is the joint distribution of the $x_i$ given the $p_i$'s.

Based on this, it is possible to construct a machine learning algorithm that receives as input a set of observations of the $x_i$ variables and the corresponding $p_i$ values. Using this information the algorithm estimates $f$ e.g. with kernel density estimation and then uses this estimations to infer the values of the $p_i$ for a never-before-seen observation of $x_i$. What is the name of such algorithm?

I have been using this for a while in an application without knowing its name. I just came up with this idea, implemented it in Python and it works fine. But now I want to use a dedicated library for the purpose to get a more efficient and faster implementation.

Comment: Could you give more concrete description of what you are actually doing?

Comment: It is a regressor for non-deterministic relations between $x$ and $p$. I am using this to predict the impact position of an electron in a silicon detector. In my case $p$ is the impact position of the electron and $x$ is the signal I measure from the detector.